# A word for a big, difficult, weird question

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes an important question that is difficult to answer? I'm attempting to get permission for something big.

Comment: "I'm stuck between Charybdis and Scylla":  meaning, either way I turn is a bad turn, but there is a *safe* passage between them, you just have to navigate it very carefully.

Comment: We even have [a tag for "conundrum" on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conundrum)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use ***conundrum***. According to [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conundrum):

***conundrum***

noun

> 1) a riddle, esp one whose answer makes a play on words
>     2) a puzzling question or problem

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is:

A **[thorny](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thorny)** problem

> [usually before noun] Causing distress, difficulty, or trouble:
>
> - a thorny problem for our team to solve

Note the synonym **[knotty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/knotty)**

(Oxford)